# C - Weird characters when I create and write into a file

Tags: c, system-calls, dot

This is my little C program:

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
  int   fd;

  if ((fd = open("./test.dot", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644)) == -1)
  {
    perror("[open]");
    return (-1);
  }
  write(fd, "digraph g {\n", sizeof("digraph g {\n"));
  write(fd, " a -> b -> c\n", sizeof(" a -> b -> c\n"));
  write(fd, " b -> d\n", sizeof(" b -> d\n"));
  write(fd, " }\n", sizeof(" }\n"));
  close(fd);
}
```

It opens a file, write some stuff and close it.

It almost works. Almost. Here's what I get when I check the content of my file:

```
digraph g {
^@ a -> b -> c
^@ b -> d
^@ }
^@
```

It seems like these characters appear after each newline. What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof("digraph g {\n")` includes null terminator, so the strings are written into the file with the `'\0'` character.

Your file viewer shows zeros using the `^@` digraph.

You should not be using `sizeof` at all - instead, use `strlen`. Better yet, use appropriate I/O functions to write strings into files without requiring you to supply their length in a separate parameter. If you must use `write`, make your own function that calls `strlen` followed by a call to `write`, so that you could avoid typing string constants twice.

Answer (score 1):

The `^@` is your viewer's representation of `'\0'`.

Example: The `sizeof(" }\n")` is 4.  `' '`, `'}'`, `'\n'`, `'\0'`,

Answer (score 1):

I think that instead of using `sizeof("string")` you should use `strlen("string")`.